# IBM AS400 based rpg/iseries

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

We need to access https api from IBM AS400 based rpg/iseries program.

To try this we have installed "Mocha W32 TN5250" but could not connect to a session.

Is it possible to make an https call from IBM AS400 based rpg/iseries program?

Comment: What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: The Mocha software is used to connect from a client (for instance your computer) to the IBM i (iSeries, AS/400). Yes, you can write RPG programs to interact with web services - using Scott Klement's software and examples (that Warren linked) is a good way to do so.

Answer (score 5):

A commonly used method is to use [Scott Klement's http package](http://www.scottklement.com/oss.html)

It's what we used when we needed to call web services from a vendor we use.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL you can use 
[HTTP functions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/IBM%20i%20Technology%20Updates/page/New%20HTTP%20functions%20added%20to%20SYSTOOLS) 
provided by IBM in SYSTOOLS.
See the 
[IBM PartnerWorld White Paper](https://www-356.ibm.com/partnerworld/wps/servlet/download/DownloadServlet?id=k4ixw2TAAIwiPCA$cnt&attachmentName=accessing_web_services_using_ibm_db2_for_i_udfs_and_udtfs.pdf).

Just embed the SQL in your RPG program.

For example:

```
dcl-s city      varchar(60);
dcl-s state     varchar(2);
dcl-s zip       varchar(10);
dcl-s area      varchar(3);
dcl-s zone      varchar(3);

EXEC SQL
SELECT city, state, zip, areacode, timezone
  INTO :city, :state, :zip, :area, :zone
  FROM XMLTABLE('$doc/NewDataSet/Table' PASSING
                XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT SYSTOOLS.HTTPGETCLOB('http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx/GetInfoByZIP?USZip=49525','')) AS "doc"
                COLUMNS
                  City      VARCHAR(60)  PATH 'CITY',
                  State     VARCHAR(2)   PATH 'STATE',
                  Zip       VARCHAR(10)  PATH 'ZIP',
                  AreaCode  VARCHAR(3)   PATH 'AREA_CODE',
                  TimeZone  VARCHAR(3)   PATH 'TIME_ZONE'
               ) AS WebServiceResult
  ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Brad Stone's solution at [BVS Tools - GetURI](http://www.bvstools.com/geturi.html/) provides a command line interface as well as an API that we've used to consume a lot of web services successfully.

(Mentioned here as a potentially lighter alternative than Scott's - absolutely no disrespect meant for Scott or his tools!)